# GGPlot2 - Drawing Arcs That Cross Zero (geom_arc)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot an arc using geom_arc that crosses 0 degree/radians however whenever I try this the package wants to reverse the direction of the arc.

In the example below I want to start at 5.76 radians and draw an arc that traverses over the top of the circle to 0.52 radians. How do I do this?

```
> arcs
  row tube   x      y radius depth    start      stop
2   1    2 381 577.85   12.7  0.17 5.759587 0.5235988

ggplot(arcs) +
  geom_arc(aes(x0 = x, y0 = y, r = radius, start = start, end = stop),color="red", size=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw the complementary arc you have to set `start=-0.5235988` and `end=2*pi-5.759587`.

---

## EDIT

No sorry. This works here because the arc is symmetric. But conceptually the good answer is `start = 5.759587 - 2*pi` and `end = 0.5235988`.

Check this non-symmetric example:

```
library(ggforce)
ggplot() + 
  geom_arc(aes(x0=381, y0=577.85, r=12.7, start=1, end=5.76)) + 
  geom_arc(aes(x0=381, y0=577.85, r=12.7, start=5.76-2*pi, end=1), 
           color = "red", size = 2)
```

[image]